# Can components created by JavaSwingBuilder reference other Yaml files?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, yaml, javabuilders

Typically when using [JavaBuilder](https://code.google.com/p/javabuilders/)<sup>[1](https://github.com/jacek99/javabuilders/tree/master)</sup> you can define a new component thusly:

Yaml myFrame.yaml:

```
JFrame(name=frame, title=frame.title, size=packed, defaultCloseOperation=exitOnClose):
    - JPanel(name=panel1, tabTitle=tab.panel1Name):
        -JTextArea(name=textArea1)
    - JPanel(name=panel2, tabTitle=tab.panel2Name):
        -JTextArea(name=textArea2)
    - JPanel(name=panel3, tabTitle=tab.panel3Name):
        -JTextArea(name=textArea3)
```

Java myFrame.java:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    private BuildResult result = SwingJavaBuilder.build(this);
}
```

JavaBuilders knows what to load by the file name. Is there a way to get JavaBuilders to load another set of files called `panel1`...`panel3` depending on the component name? This would be so one part of my application can write the yaml files out and then I can 'Hot Deploy' them when my JFrame is built (with `private BuildResult result = SwingJavaBuilder.build(this);`)

---

My intention is to read a directory looking for a file/set of files that might read like so:

```
my.dir.panel1=available
my.dir.panel1.textArea1=available
my.dir.panel1.textArea1.default=Declarative GUIs!
my.dir.panel1.textArea2=unavailable
my.dir.panel2=available
my.dir.panel2.textArea1=available
my.dir.panel3=available
my.dir.panel3.textArea1=available
my.dir.panel4=unavailable
my.dir.panel4.textArea1=unavailable
```

And then use that to populate components in Swing. I can write out the Yaml files programmatically with snakeYaml dependant on what is 'available' in the above properties file *but* if I can avoid rewriting the `JFrame` section (which may contain a variety of other components that *won't* change) in the Yaml file that would be ideal.

The only other way I can think of this is to have multiple results created in Java like so

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    private BuildResult frankenResult = SwingJavaBuilder.build(this);
    private BuildResult subReult1 = SwingJavaBuilder.build(new MyPanel());

    JFrame myFrame = (JFrame)result.get("myFrame");
    JPanel myPanel = (JPanel)result.get("panel1");
    myFrame.add(myPanel);
}
```

But thinking about it I'm not certain I can make this call `SwingJavaBuilder.build(new MyPanel());`

**So how can I create subsets of Components in a separate yaml file and then reference them in a main Yaml file?**

<sub>1: [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/jacek99/javabuilders/tree/master)</sub>

Comment: Did you ever have any success with this?

Comment: @Monksy theoretically there's a way.  Not tried it yet.